# What does 'ever' modify?

Tags: adverbs, modifiers

> It was my first game ever.

Does *ever* modify *was* or *first*?

> This is my first time ever playing basketball.

Does *ever* modify *is* or *first*?

Comment: Your sentences are shortened versions of _It was the first game I had ever taken part in_ and _This is the first time I have ever played basketball_.

Comment: It's a modifier in the copular VP "was my first game ever".

Comment: “the first time ever I saw your face . . .”

Comment: @BillJ Not in the NP "first game ever"?

Comment: This very good question, probably by a native speaker, belongs on  EL&U. Please be more careful with migrating questions!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Short answer - it modifies 'first'. It is very common to say something is the '*first ever*' to make it clear that it is the *absolute first*.

For example, what would you think if someone asked "*what was your first meal*"? Would you think they meant your first meal *of the day* (ie your breakfast this morning) or the first meal *ever in your life*?

Saying '*first ever*' can remove ambiguity, add specificity, or just add emphasis.

Comment: I get that *ever* often follows *first* and thus *first ever* is a common string. I also definitely agree with your analysis. But what is your *evidence* that 'ever' is modifying *first* and not *was*?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore What else could it be modifying? The fact that you could omit the word 'game' in some contexts and say "that was my first ever" should be an indicator. You couldn't omit the word 'first' and make any sense. "That was my ever game" would not mean anything.

Comment: _First_ is a superlative,  the negative trigger that licenses _ever_. It can be _the first ever, the last ever, the biggest and best ever_, but not *_the seventeenth ever_. Superlatives and comparatives are **really** complex constructions. And _ever_ can't be said to "modify" anything in a normal way  -- it integrates over the time span, looking for inflection points or zeros.

Comment: @JohnLawler that's not *exactly* right... yes, 'first' is a superlative, but within any given context. You could be the first today, the first this month, the first this year etc... and of course, the first *ever*. Also, if the seventeenth time doing something was still a really low number in the context there would be nothing wrong with saying, for example, "it's only the seventeenth time I've ever done it". Again, it would make it clear you meant the seventeenth time in your life, not the seventeenth time so far today.

Comment: @Astralbee - try it without _only_, and without other negative triggers. [_Ever_ requires a negative trigger](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63728/15299), and _seventeenth_ is very hard to motivate as negation.

Comment: I don't agree that "ever" is modifying "first". If it were part of the NP "first game ever" it would be modifying the nominal "game", not the determiner "first". A modifier in the copular VP makes more sense to me.

Comment: @JohnLawler "The comet is expected to pass Earth again this year. It'll be the seventeenth time ever." I agree with what you're saying, but I don't find it very hard to motivate such words.

Comment: @BillJ But sometimes "ever" is buried in a NP, making it difficult to modify a verb. E.g.: "We should have prizes for the first gargling contest ever." It gets even more buried if we write "the first ever gargling contest". (Some people would even hyphenate "first-ever".) And of course if we move the PP to the front, "ever" must move with it (mandatory).

Comment: _Ever_ has the same category as _at any time, in springtime,_ or _as soon as you like_. It's a temporal quantifier and normally part of the verb phrase, if it's not just an adverbial adjunct.

Comment: @JohnLawler Here I think it's part of the NP, albeit licensed by *first.* We could have for instance "My first game ever was immortalised in the film *David v Goliath*" or summat similar.

Comment: If you want to. It doesn't matter what it modifies; it's part of the construction and that's good enough.